# What would the distribution curve of a 2d6 + card(s) look like?

Tags: statistics

I'm developing a new RPG and was wanting to use things readily available in most homes so as not to create a burden to play. The solution I came up with was 2d6, which the max is 12, and a deck of cards which Aces = 2, and kings & jokers (if used) = 13. The reasoning behind this is that it would be 1/4 of a d100, which quite a few games use.

I’ll likely use this for playing modern day/near future games. I’m aiming for it to be reasonably rules light, probably FATE- or GURPS-esque.

One of the things I was going to do with it (to make things interesting) is that one card could be played per level of the skill (or whatever), but above the 1st card, complications would arise, so players have to balance "do I add more cards in order to increase the likelihood of success... or do I simply let this fail". BUT in order to understand this more fully, I need the curve to analyze

Comment: @cpcodes See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: So, each card-draw is adding 2-13? With double weighting on the 2 & (possibly) 13?

Comment: @Adeptus double weighting on the 2, and 1.5 on the 13 (there are only 2 jokers) - reason being is that I need a *minimum* of 4 to represent 1/4 of a d100

Answer (score 3):

[AnyDice](https://anydice.com/program/10d69) can show you the spread of results from a "dice" with arbitrary sides. Here I have created one that gives the result of your card-draw.

[image: AnyDice output of card-draw]

Adding in the 2d6 as well, gives [this](https://anydice.com/program/10d6a):

[image: AnyDice output of 2d6 + card-draw]

Comment: Would things change if a player is able to put more cards down to get larger numbers? (i.e. a 2 and a 5 to get a 7, and a 12 for their roll) up to a maximum of let's say... 5 or 6 additional cards

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "things". The values you'd be able to get and probabilities associated with these would obviously be different, but the shape of the distribution would be similar (a normal distribution, bell-shaped)

Comment: Follow the second link in my answer. See the equation "2d6 + d{...}". Put a number before that second "d" to show multiple card draws. Note: these all assume replacing the card after each draw. If you draw and leave it out, the chance of getting the same number again will be less, and so the chance of getting any other number will be higher.

Comment: @Adeptus that would be a headache to reshuffle every time a card was drawn. I was thinking on something like a traditional card hand that is used. So there would be 3 things going on 1) a hand of X# of cards 2) a used pile, which would be reshuffled back into the deck after so much time and 3) the deck itself from which to draw.

Comment: Please don't use comments to request additional follow-up work outside the scope of the original question. Ask a new question instead so people can provide answers with our actual Q&A mechanisms.